# My loop for is getting slower and slower Python

Tags: python, selenium, loops

i'm doing a web scraping using selenium web driver where I need to send thousands of registers to a field in website to download a .csv with the info that i need about this registers.

The solution that i found to send all this register is

```
df = pd.read_csv('arMestre.csv')

    x = 0
    y = 200
    i = 0
    
    while i < 5:
            t1 = time.time()
            element.send_keys(df[x:y].to_string(header=False, index=False) + "\n")
            i += 1
            x = y+1
            y += 200
            t2 = time.time()
            print(t2-t1)
```

I built this loop only for a test, and my test get this amount of seconds for loop:

```
7.61 - first loop
13.44 - second loop 
23.53 - third loop 
28.70 - fourth loop
35.12 - fifith loop
```

The registers are numbers like this and I have to consult 19k of them

```
93040132242591
93040132254075
93040132277390
93040132314829
93040132426137
93040132838473
93040134252423
93040134211776
```

First, why this happen?
Second, there is a better/faster way to do it?

I'm not expert on Python, i've start about a month to make this kind of job.

Comment: Unless the page reloads each time, you do not need to redo the search in every loop.  You can do `box = driver.find_element(...)` before the loop starts, then just do `box.send_keys` inside the loop.

Comment: Thanks for advice @TimRoberts, but even with this adjust nothing changes with the time

Comment: Is it possible the web site you're yanking on is throttling your bandwidth to prevent you from doing what you're trying to do?

Comment: No, isn't @TimRoberts

Comment: Try with: driver.find_element(By.ID, "docs").send_keys(df1 + "\n");  to see if it's any faster... (it should be, but no idea why the time is getting larger each iteration... at first I thought it might be the slice, but that's before you get the time...)

Comment: What you are doing here is a little odd since there is no wait at all.  I would try/catch those send keys calls and see if any exceptions are being thrown.  Seems like you should get a bunch of non-interactable messages.  The driver is going to attempt to scroll the field into view, then type if it's interactable...  if scrolling is necessary maybe there's something affecting that in your inputs.   You might also print the strings you are sending next to the times.  Maybe you're not sending what you think...

Comment: Please double-check to make sure the indentation of your code is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the tips @pcalkins, I couldn't solve the problem, but i managed to deal with this using an another bigger loop who make this in baths of 5 times sending 200 registers at time after this it come back and send more 5 baths of 200 in a little loop. Every time the loops get the same time (8; 13; 22, 28, 33 seconds) funny right?

Comment: Yes... it really sounds like some sort of array traversal thing where it's going back to zero each time... or some kind of recursion.  No idea what's going on there.  Mayybe the text input field is getting longer each time.  Selenium may clear that before typing, but not real sure.

Comment: what this could be is that the DOM is getting a little larger each time... (maybe it tracks previous searches or something, or it just hides some of the old DOM)  That would make the find method take a little longer to traverse the DOM nodes each time.

Comment: Actually this make sense, the problem seems to be just with the selenium, i made some tests to past this values in another places, the loop was way faster every time. Many thanks for your dedication thru my problem. 
I'm having a new problem in this code and post it few minutes ago a new question, could you see if there a way to help me? :) @pcalkins